# Help Understanding Convolution Filter Formulation

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I'm reading [Computer Vision: Algorithms and Applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/) wich is available online as a PDF and on Chapter 3.2 page 111 it introduces convolution operators for images giving the formulation:

$g(i, j) = \Sigma_{k,l} f(i − k, j − l)h(k, l) = \Sigma_{k,l}f(k, l)h(i − k, j − l)$

since $(i,j)$ are pixel coordinates $f$ is the pixel intensity function for the image we're convolving and $h$ is the function for the convolution matrix it makes sense to me that $g(i,j)$ is equal to the first sum expression but I can't wrap my head around how this is equivalent to the second sum expression. If someone could explain this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It's just a change of variables. You could replace `k` by e.g. `k+5` or in this case `i-k` and the sum would be the same. You're just summing in a different order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te elaborate on nikie's comment that it is just a change of variables, consider the following.

Suppose that the original image is a single pixel of intensity $1$ at point $(0,0)$
and all other pixels have intensity $0$. Then,
the result of the convolution of this image is $h(i,j)$, that is, this
single pixel in the original image produces pixel intensity $h(i,j)$ at
the point $(i,j)$.  The actual image is a whole bunch of pixels, though, at
different points, and the superposition principle says that the resulting
pixel intensity $g(i,j)$ at point $(i,j)$ is the sum of of the pixel intensities
produced by the various pixels in the original image. 
There are two ways of calculating $g(i,j)$.
Let's go through the pixels in the original image in order of their
distance from the point $(i,j)$.  Well, the point $(i-k,j-l)$ is at distance
$(k,l)$ from $(i,j)$ and the pixel intensity $f(i-k,j-l)$ there
produces intensity $f(i-k,j-l)h(k,l)$ at $(i,j)$.  This gives the first
formula
$$g(i,j) = \sum_k\sum_l f(i-k,j-l)h(k,l).$$
Alternatively, we can go through the pixels in natural order and ask
what intensity the pixel $f(k,l)$ produces at the point $(i,j)$. Well,
the distance is $(i-k,j-l)$ and so the intensity is $f(k,l)h(i-k,j-l)$
giving
$$g(i,j) = \sum_k\sum_l f(k,l)h(i-k,j-l).$$